# javascript - Menu show/hide não funciona

Tags: javascript, menu, submenu

```
function dpdShowHide(){
var orgBtn = getElementById('organizador');
var dpdOrg = getElementById('org-dpd-list');
    if (orgBtn !== false) {
        dpdOrg.visibility('none')
    }
    else{
        dpdOrg.visibility('block')
    }
}
```

Então, meu problema é o seguinte, to tentando fazer um menu oculto (uma ul) aparecer e desaparecer ao clicar na li(elemento pai dessa outra ul), porém não está funcionando

Comment: Você poderia colocar também o código do HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Será isto?

```html
<script>
function dpdShowHide(ele){

    dpdOrg = ele.children[0];
    if (dpdOrg.style.display == 'none') {
        dpdOrg.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
       dpdOrg.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

var orgBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('organizador');
for (var i = 0 ; i < orgBtns.length; i++) {
    orgBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
       dpdShowHide();
    });
}

</script>

<ul>
       <li>
          li
       </li>
       <li class="organizador" onclick="dpdShowHide(this)">sub ul1
           <ul id="org-dpd-list" style="display: none">
              <li>sub li</li>
              <li>sub li</li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
          li
       </li>
       <li class="organizador" onclick="dpdShowHide(this)">sub ul2
           <ul id="org-dpd-list" style="display: none">
              <li>sub li</li>
              <li>sub li</li>
           </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Exato, obrigado cara, mas eu tenho mais uma dúvida, como eu faria pra esse mesmo código funcionar em vários botões no mesmo menu, porém, sem ter que repetir...E desculpa ficar tomando seu tempo

Comment: Pode dar atributos data, 1 secs vou fazer

Comment: Feito @MuriloGambôa